# Serving index.py on GAE without HTML?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

This user-input math function (index.py) works in command line, and it and app.yaml file uploaded to and confirmed deployed from GAE, but throws internal server 500 error. Can these print statements be served without HTML...would that be what's causing server error?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import cgi
import math


print "Content-type: text/html"


exp = input('Enter base and exponent, separated by comma.\n') 

print '= %d \n' % math.pow(*exp)
```

app.yaml

```
application:  python-math 
version: 1 
runtime: python27 
api_version: 1

threadsafe: false 
handlers:
-url: /stylesheets/
static_dir: stylesheets
-url: /.*
script: index.py
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the "input" function... It doesn't quite make sense in a web setting, as the HTTP protocol doesn't have a mechanism for prompting for user input while it is delivering a page.

Here are a couple of things to try:

- Read through the [Python appengine example](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/helloworld) and try to see how that might be applicable
- You could develop a page that has a HTML form that requests the input.  When the user presses the form's "ok" button, it would make another request to the server, which would provide the result.

Comment: Thanks for kind reply, I've done a form and datastore previously with GAE and with PHP/MySQL...I was just hoping that being served from GAE the "print" would magically read the function's input, even without HTML. Guess not. I wish there were a way to go from command line environment to deployment without forms, as it takes a lot of the fun out of it, for me anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You can take parameter without a form if you use a `self.request.get('variable')` to get your parameters over HTTP GET without using a form.